# Cannot pass field values through to related list?

Tags: lookup, relationships, master-detail

I am attempting to create a master-detail relationship on an object that is a detail record of two other objects in a many-to-many relationship. Unfortunately, it appears that the platform does not allow for this kind of schema.

As a workaround, I have created a lookup relationship instead of a master-detail, but when I try to configure the information appearing in the related list, I am unable to "pass through" the fields from the related object to the child record in the lookup relationship.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried creating formula fields on the child object?

Comment: What is "pass through"? Your question is not clear.

Comment: It was a reference to pulling values across the junction object, and displaying them in the related lists of either Master record in the MD relationship.